# Mock a function which has an out parameter of type const char**

Tags: c++, c++98

I need to mock a c api "class" which is basically a struct containing a set of function pointers. Here's is my approach. Is it valid in your opinion or can you suggest a better approach?

```
typedef struct MockCApi: public CApi
{
    MockCApi()
    {
        // Hook in function
        getName = nameFunc;
    }

    static void reset()
    {
        handle.clear(); 
        name.clear();
        returnValue.clear();
    }

    static ReturnType nameFunc(HandleType _handle, const char** _name)
    {
        handle.push_back(_handle);

        poppedNames.push_back(name.front());
        *_name = poppedNames.back().c_str();

        ReturnType _returnValue = returnValue.front();
        returnValue.pop_front();
        return _returnValue;
    }

    static std::deque<HandleType> handle;
    static std::deque<std::string> name;
    static std::deque<ReturnType> returnValue;
private:
    static std::deque<std::string> poppedNames;
};
```

**UPDATE**

Another approach I have in mind is to use `std::vector`'s and `std::vector::iterator`'s instead of `std::queue`'s. The iterator will be incremented each time I "use" a value in the vector.

Comment: Are you asking how to simulate a class using a structure? What does it mean when you say is it 'valid '?

Comment: I need to create a mock which I can use in my unit tests. In other words, I need to save the arguments passed to the function pointed to by CApi::getName. Which I can then check in the unit test. I also wish to be able to control the value returned by this function on a test by test bases. By 'valid' I simply meant if there are any bugs in my code as the use of c_str and const char** is a little alien to me.

Comment: Strictly for unit testing?   If so, use a framework like CxxTest or CUnit, or the Google test framework is also good, I've heard.  When you test a particular class, try creating a derived class instead, which lets you inject data or access data you wouldn't otherwise have access to.

Comment: Google Mock wont work in this case because the function pointers in the struct, point to global functions. This is why I'm pointing them to the static method nameFunc.